Wrapping a third-party Java library with Rascal MPL Vallang
How do I wrap a Java library with Vallang, I already know how to access a Java library from Rascal but I would like to know how to wrapper/adapt a third-party Java library so I can call it from Rascal.


Create a main java class that has a constructor that takes IRascalValueFactory and TypeStore as parameters. You need them later so store in the fields.
Write a main rascal module with type definitions; data types for example. These definitions end up in the TypeStore. public MyClass(IRascalValueFactory vf, TypeStore store) { this.vf = vf; this.store = store; }
Add a first java function to the rascal module and its corresponding public java method with the same name in the java class. Have a look in Prelude.java in the Rascal project for many examples. @javaClass{MyClass} java list[int] myFunction(loc l); with public IInteger myFunction(ISourceLocation l) { ... } in MyClass.
Use the IRascalValueFactory and the TypeStore to create instances of rascal IValue:


vf.listWriter and vf.setWriter for fast creation of sets and lists.
vf.string(..)
if.constructor(..)

For advanced tricks you can also instantiate rascal functions from java lambda's with vf.function.
Sometimes you need to construct rascal Type instances yourself. You can add a TypeFactory parameters to the above constructor, or use TypeFactory.getInstance()`. The factory can be used to make any type rascal may need. The most common usecase is for wrapping java lambda's: rascal wants to know the function's static type.
Try to use URIResolverRegistry.getInstance to open streams for file IO from loc  parameters. They are ISourceLocation instances on the java side. If you do this the library you wrap will work for all kinds of locations, which will feel natural from the rascal side.
NB. There is hardly any typechecking by the vallang library. In debug mode with -ea there are runtime null checks. But not when asserts are disabled. So you have to make sure that runtime types of values align with the static types of data constructors and function types. If you make mistakes you get NPE's and ClassCastExceptions. And then you know what to fix.
It's best to catch java exceptions in the outermost java method that links to the Rascal function. There you rethrow using the static methods of RuntimeExceptionFactory‘ or you throw a rascal exception yourself: throw new Throw(val)`
Examples:

The flybytes project wraps the ASM library
The clair project wraps the eclipse CDT
The standard library of the rascal project wraps lucene in analysis::text
lang::json::IO wraps gson
lang::XML::IO wraps jsoup
lang::html::IO wraps jsoup too
lang::csv::IO
The JDBC module in the library
Etc.

The IO stuff is easier to read and understand because of the conceptual
Simplicity, however there is a lot of type manipulation at runtime which makes it less representative of simple wrappers.
The other wrappers are conceptually very complete and therefore a bit complex, but they are also straightforward mappings between the two worlds.

Thanks Jurgen I will try that out I am trying to implement WebSocket for my CLI

Oooo that's great! If you're interested in sharing your results in open source we might adopt it later for util::WebServer. Which library are you using?

Ok I will do that
